# To return status and data to html in PHP

Tags: php, email, post

I am trying to get the result of mail() from PHP to jquery using post(). How can I set post() in JQuery and send the status of the mail in PHP?

In .php

```
$status = mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
if ($status) {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo 'Mail sent!';
} else {
    http_response_code(500);    
    echo 'Something went wrong!';
}
```

In JQuery,

```
$.post('test.php', data, function(data) {
  alert('data: ' + data);
})
```

Should I have to return data from php?

Comment: Is there any error you're getting? Check your console there maybe an error on empty `data` as far as I know you can't send and empty data like this

Comment: There is no error. The mail is going out alright. I can't get the alert. Oops, it is alert('data: ' + data) in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best if you use the [deferred API](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) from jQuery for this one, using `.done()` to handle to 200 response and `.fail()` for the 500.

```
$.post('test.php', data)
  .done(data => { 
    alert('Success: ' + data) // should be "Success: Mail sent!"
  }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
    alert('Failed: ' + jqXHR.responseText) // should be "Fail: Something went wrong!"
  })
```

Comment: @Gene9y I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment

Comment: At least it throws the error which means it is responding to the code.

Comment: @Gene9y so you're saying you get the "Fail" message alerted? If that's the case, then `mail()` is returning `false` in your PHP, meaning it failed

Comment: @Gene9y the client-side (JavaScript) code will make absolutely zero difference to your PHP execution. The code in my answer does nothing differently to the code in your question other than add an error handler.

Comment: @Gene9y time to check your browser's _Network_ console. What is the response status code? Is the response text _"Something went wrong!"_ from your code or is it something else? Are there any PHP errors logged anywhere?

Comment: Well something is causing your request to fail. How about answering my other questions?

Comment: Try wrapping the php function with a try...catch block and use the `getMessage()` function on the Exception object to get the string error message.  Print that if you catch an Exception.  If you're using ajax, it will return whatever is printed on the page to your callback function on the client-side Javascript which should print a message and send a 200 no matter what since it will either work or catch the error.

Comment: No, checked network again. The .js returns 304 error.

Comment: I changed some thing in html. Worked! Many thanks, Phil.

Answer (score 0):

Well without more detailed error info, it's gonna be hard to say.  But here is my go-to vanilla Ajax request sender that I made sometime ago.

```
class AjaxRequest{
    constructor(){
        this.httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    setup(type, url, func){
        func = func || function() { };

        function callbackFunc(){
            if (this.httpReq.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.httpReq.status === 200) {
                    let data = this.httpReq.response;
                    //console.log("Returned from ajax query: ", data);
                    func(data);
                }
                // Catch errors here
                else {
                    console.log('There was a problem with the request.');
                }
            }
        }
        this.httpReq.open(type, url);
        this.httpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        this.httpReq.onreadystatechange = callbackFunc.bind(this);
    }
    send(params){
        params = params || {};
        params = JSON.stringify(params);
        this.httpReq.send(params);
    }
}
```

To use it, instantiate it, setup() with request type, URL, and callback.

So for your case...

```
let ajax = new AjaxRequest();
ajax.setup('POST', 'test.php', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
ajax.send(); //pass in data that you want to send here
```